# How to retrieve llvm::Instruction address after JIT code generation?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

While using `llvm::IRBuilder`, I collect `llvm::Instruction`s mapped with code locations and my wish is to be able to retrieve memory location of these instructions in the form {void* start, void* end} after the code generation has been done by the JIT compiler, is this possible ? (the intend is to insert software breakpoints and retrieve instruction from EIP when breaking).

Comment: Nice question. Make sure to also ask this on llvm-dev mailing list.

Comment: I've just done it, thank you for giving me the idea :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not directly possible to do this for individual instructions, but you can get at least the address of the basic block that your instruction is in through the static [BlockAddress](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1BlockAddress.html) helpers. Of course, as pointed out on the mailing list, any number of things could have happened to the LLVM instruction, or the whole basic block could have been optimised away.